# how to count records in prisma io?

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I am executing a query but the result of the account adds the letter "n", I don't understand why when I execute the query in mysql console it shows it correctly.

```
const client = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT idClient, COUNT(*) as totalCount FROM sales GROUP BY idClient`;
console.log(client)
```

[image]

executing the same query but in heidiSQL.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Numbers with an `n` postfix denote the BigInt type in JavaScript [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). This is probably due to some `queryRaw` changes that were made in v4.0.0. The Integer results are now being returned as BigInt. `You must change your code to handle the new type`. See this [section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/upgrade-guides/upgrading-versions/upgrading-to-prisma-4#raw-query-type-mapping-scalar-values-are-now-deserialized-as-their-correct-javascript-types) of the upgrade guide.

Example: Given this Schema file

```
model Customers {
  id  Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  customerName String
  country String
}
```

and this script file

```
async function main() {

  await prisma.customers.createMany({
    data: [
      {
        country: 'USA',
        customerName: 'John Doe',
      },
      {
        country: 'Germany',
        customerName: 'Jane Doe',
      },
      {
        country: 'Canada',
        customerName: 'Adams Doe',
      },
    ],
  });

  const clients = await prisma.customers.groupBy({
    by: ['country'],
    _count: true,
  });
  console.log("Using normal client query with groupBy ")
  console.log(clients);

  const clientsWithRawQuery =
    await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT Country, COUNT(country) as totalCount
FROM Customers GROUP BY Country`;
  console.log("\n Using queryRaw")
  console.log(clientsWithRawQuery);

  console.log(
    'Before Conversion: Typeof Count:',
    typeof clientsWithRawQuery[0].totalCount
  );

  clientsWithRawQuery.forEach((countryObject) => {
    countryObject.totalCount = Number(countryObject.totalCount);
  });

  console.log(
    'After Conversion: Typeof Count:',
    typeof clientsWithRawQuery[0].totalCount
  );
  console.log('\n', clientsWithRawQuery)
}
```

The output is

```
Using normal client query with groupBy 
[
  { _count: 2, country: 'Canada' },
  { _count: 2, country: 'Germany' },
  { _count: 2, country: 'USA' }
]

 Using queryRaw
[
  { Country: 'Canada', totalCount: 2n },
  { Country: 'Germany', totalCount: 2n },
  { Country: 'USA', totalCount: 2n }
]
Before Conversion: Typeof Count: bigint
After Conversion: Typeof Count: number

 [
  { Country: 'Canada', totalCount: 2 },
  { Country: 'Germany', totalCount: 2 },
  { Country: 'USA', totalCount: 2 }
]
```